# Separating CSV (one column) into many columns on delimiter (comma)

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, miller

I have a CSV with ~50 comma-separated values in one column that I want to separate into separate columns. The header is line 1. This should be really simple, and I've tried a lot surrounding `awk` and `mlr` but haven't been able to adapt anything I've seen in order to separate a single column into many columns using a comma as a delimiter.

My process:

1. I used `mlr` to combine hundreds of CSVs into one CSV:

   ```bash
   mlr --icsv cat *.csv > filename.txt
   mlr --ocsv unsparsify filename.txt > filename.csv
   ```
2. Now I have a CSV with one column; in that column are ~50 comma-separated values that I want to explode into many columns.

Comment: Add please a sample input file

Comment: In a CSV (comma-separated-value) file, the values are delimited by commas. It's unclear what you want to do to the data if the fields are _already_ delimited by commas.  Seeing an explicit example would be good.  I suppose that we may _assume_ that you are talking about commas in a _quoted_ field, but you never actually say this and you show no examples of the data.

Comment: Are there other columns in addition to this one with 50 comma-separated values in it? Please add sample input and expected output. Obviously use something like 3 instead of 50 nested columns.

Comment: what about this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712982/195582

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You should add always some input and output sample file.

I seem to have understood that you have an input of this type, a csv in which a column contains a CSV inside (in example here, the `a` field)

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,2,3 | aa | aa |
| 4,7,9 | ff | ff |

The raw CSV is this:

```
a,b,c
"1,2,3",aa,aa
"4,7,9",ff,ff
```

Using miller and [nest verb](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#nest), you can run

```
mlr --csv nest --explode --values --across-fields -f a --nested-fs "," input_01.csv > output.csv
```

to have

| a_1 | a_2 | a_3 | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | aa | aa |
| 4 | 7 | 9 | ff | ff |

The raw output is

```
a_1,a_2,a_3,b,c
1,2,3,aa,aa
4,7,9,ff,ff
```

Comment: @user536893 what about this answer?

Comment: perfect, thanks